# AppDelegate Class not Available to Obj-C Embedded Library in iOS Swift App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, appdelegate, swizzling

I have a library written in Objective C, published as a Cocoapod. Part of what the library does is some swizzling of the AppDelegate class of any app that it is added to. When the library is added to a simple Objective-C app (a single-page app with nothing in it), the callback methods are swizzled properly and everyone is happy. However, when the library is added to a similar Swift app, the swizzling fails because the AppDelegate is null (or nil).

Here is a peek at the code within the library:

(Note: this method is called from the UIResponder's **load:** method.)

### UIResponder+MyCustomMethods.m

```
/**
 *  This class swizzles the methods needed to observe protocol methods
 */
@implementation UIResponder (WTAutomatics)

...

+ (void)swizzleAppDelegate:(SEL)original with:(SEL)replacement forProtocol:(Protocol *)protocol
{
    id appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Class appDelegate = [appDel class];
    // Alternatively, we can do this. Both work the same.
    // Class appDelegate = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] class];

    NSLog(@"Starting swizzle: %@", NSStringFromSelector(original));    
    if (!appDelegate) {
        WTLog(@"Failed to swizzle because appDelegate is null.");
        return;
    }

    if (class_conformsToProtocol(appDelegate, protocol)) {
        // Do the method swizzling
        ...
    }
}
```

In the code above, the value of appDelegate is valid and the swizzling works in any Objective C app. However, **appDelegate is null when this is run within a *Swift* app** and the swizzle fails.

Is there some difference in the order of initialization of the application delegate between the two languages? Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: How does this even work in the Obj-c app?   +load should be called before main, and main is where the UIApplication is created & initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain how this is working for you in the Obj-C application case.   In my test, the +load is called before the application's main() method, which is where UIApplication is created and initialized.  In my test, the following prints (null) for both lines:

```
@interface UIResponder (blah)
@end
@implementation UIResponder (blah)
+ (void) load
{
    NSLog( @"application: %@", [UIApplication sharedApplication] );
    NSLog( @"delegate:    %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] );
}
@end
```

Here's a version that does what you want:

```
@interface UIResponder (blah)
@end
@implementation UIResponder (blah)
+ (void) load
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(didFinishLaunching:) name: UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object: nil];

}
+ (void) didFinishLaunching: (NSNotification*) n
{
    NSLog( @"application: %@", [UIApplication sharedApplication] );
    NSLog( @"delegate:    %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] );
}
@end
```

Furthermore, I don't think it is advisable to implement +load in a category extension because you don't know if that is overriding some +load method defined on the class itself.  I believe when that is the case it is undefined which one is called?  I'd have to check.   A better solution might be to create your own UIResponder-derived class and put your +load shim there.

Comment: I love this solution! I implemented the observer and it worked just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Apple Docs: +load**
Invoked whenever a class or category is added to the Objective-C runtime; implement this method to perform class-specific behavior upon loading.

It looks like your AppDelegate isn't loaded yet. Try to call your swizzling from another place. E.g.

```
+(void)initialize{
[self swizzle...];
```

}

Comment: I attempted this technique, but the initialize method is never called on the UIResponder class. I think because we're only using static methods there? Any way, all my code is never called when I use it.